# running mysqldbcompare inside a powershell script

Tags: mysql, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to execute `mysqldbcompare` from within PowerShell.

The basic command is:

`mysqldbcompare --server1=userName:password@1.2.3.4:3306 --server2=username:password@5.6.7.8:3306 dbname:dbname --run-all-tests --changes-for=server2 --skip-data-check --skip-row-count --skip-table-options --disable-binary-logging -dsql`

This works fine when run in a standard cmd window.

However, I need the relevant parts to be dynamic, so I have something like:

```
#Server 1
$user1    = "username"
$pass1    = "password"
$db1addr  = "1.2.3.4"
$db1Port  = "3306"
$schema1  = "dbname"

#Server 2
$user2    = $user1
$pass2    = $pass1
$db2addr  = "5.6.7.8"
$db2port  = $db1port
$schema2  = $schema1
```

I have then tried running

```
& 'mysqldbcompare --server1=$user1:$pass1@$db1addr:$db1Port --server2=$user2:$pass2@$db2addr:$db2Port $schema1:$schema2 --run-all-tests --changes-for=server2 --skip-data-check --skip-row-count --skip-table-options --disable-binary-logging -dsql'
```

.

```
cmd \c 'mysqldbcompare --server1=$user1:$pass1@$db1addr:$db1Port --server2=$user2:$pass2@$db2addr:$db2Port $schema1:$schema2 --run-all-tests --changes-for=server2 --skip-data-check --skip-row-count --skip-table-options --disable-binary-logging -dsql'
```

.

```
$args = @('--server1=$user1:$pass1@$db1addr:$db1Port','--server2=$user2:$pass2@$db2addr:$db2Port','$schema1:$schema2','--run-all-tests','--changes-for=server2','--skip-data-check','--skip-row-count','--skip-table-options','--disable-binary-logging','-dsql')
& 'mysqldbcompare' $args
```

I've also tried 'building' the command e.g.

```
$args = @("--server1=".$user1.":".$pass1."@".$db........
```

which also fails.

Most of the errors tend to be similar to:

```
mysqldbcompare.exe : Usage: mysqldbcompare.exe --server1=user:pass@host:port:socket --server2=user:pass@host:port
:socket db1:db2
At C:\dbCompare.ps1:27 char:2
+ & <<<<  'mysqldbcompare' $args
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Usage: mysqldbc...:socket db1:db2:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError


mysqldbcompare.exe: error: Server1 connection values invalid: Connection '$db1addr:$db1Port' cannot be parsed. Pl
ease review the used connection string (accepted formats: <user>[:<password>]@<host>[:<port>][:<socket>] or <logi
n-path>[:<port>][:<socket>]).
```

If I type the values directly into `$args`, rather than using dynamic variables though, it works ok.

Is there a way of running this from within PowerShell?

Comment: Try `$args = @("--server1=${user1}:${pass1}@${db1addr}:${db1Port}", ...)`. Variables are not expanded inside single-quoted strings. The curly brackets are to make sure that the colons are not interpreted as scope operators.

Comment: cheers, that has fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third approach was almost correct, except that you used single-quoted strings. Single quotes are for defining literal strings without any expansion. To have variables/expressions expanded in a string you must use double-quotes.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $s = 'foo'
PS C:\> '-$s-'
-$s-
PS C:\> "-$s-"
-foo-
```

Also, you need to put curly brackets around variable names if they're followed by a colon, because PowerShell interprets characters between `$` and `:` as scope names.

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> $s = 'foo'
PS C:\> "$s:23

PS C:\> "${s}:23"
foo:23
```

Change this:

```psh
$args = @('--server1=$user1:$pass1@$db1addr:$db1Port',
          '--server2=$user2:$pass2@$db2addr:$db2Port',
          '$schema1:$schema2',
          '--run-all-tests',
          '--changes-for=server2',
          '--skip-data-check',
          '--skip-row-count',
          '--skip-table-options',
          '--disable-binary-logging',
          '-dsql'
        )
& 'mysqldbcompare' $args
```

into this:

```psh
$args = "--server1=${user1}:${pass1}@${db1addr}:${db1Port}",
        "--server2=${user2}:${pass2}@${db2addr}:${db2Port}",
        "${schema1}:$schema2}",
        '--run-all-tests',
        '--changes-for=server2',
        '--skip-data-check',
        '--skip-row-count',
        '--skip-table-options',
        '--disable-binary-logging',
        '-dsql'
& 'mysqldbcompare' $args
```

and the problem should disappear.